# hasMany combo box in cakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am a new cake baker. I developing a web site for cars, where each carcategory has many cars, and each car belongs only to one carcategory. In my Cars model, I wrote the following code:

```
    class Cars extends AppModel 
    {
     var $name = 'Cars';
     var $belongsTo = array('Carcategory','User');
    }
```

And in my Carcategory model, I wrote the following code:

```
    class Carcategory extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'Carcategory';
        var $hasMany = array(
        'Car' => array(
            'className'     => 'Car',
            'foreignKey'    => 'carcategory_id',
            'order'    => 'carcategory.name ASC',
            'dependent'=> true
        )
    );

}
```

And in my car_controller, I wrote the following code:

```
    function beforeFilter(){
 $this->set('car_categories',$this->Carcategory->find('list', array('order' => 'name')));
  }
```

And in my car view, I wrote the following code:

```
echo $form->input('carcategory_id', array('options' => $car_categories, 'label' => 'Cars Categories : ', 'class' => 'short'));
```

My database tables are as the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE `carcategories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;  

     CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `motorcc` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `details` text character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `carcategory_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

I have named the first table carcategory, because I might add another services to my site, and these services might have other categories
My code generates the following error

```
    Notice (8): Undefined property: CarsController::$Carcategory [APP\controllers\cars_controller.php, line 14]
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in c:\wamp\www\work\cake\app\controllers\cars_controller.php on line 14
```

I cannot figure out what is the wrong in my code. Please give me a hand
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're not sticking to the CakePHP naming conventions. (Check them out [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/24/Model-and-Database-Conventions)) Doing this would help you spot little mistakes, like the classname for your model is *Cars* when it should be *Car*. I would also rename your table to `car_categories` and hence all occurrences of `Carcategory` to `CarCategory`.

**models/car.php**

```
class Car extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Car';
    var $belongsTo = array('CarCategory', 'User');
}
```

**models/car_category.php**

```
class CarCategory extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'CarCategory';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Car' => array(
            'className' => 'Car',
            'foreignKey' => 'car_category_id',
            'order' => 'CarCategory.name ASC',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}
```

**controllers/cars_controller.php**

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->set('carCategories', $this->Car->CarCategory->find('list'));
}
```

Note: You don't need to specify the order because you've already mentioned it in the model as the default order. Also, note the naming conventions for the view variable. This would let us do some CakePHP magic and simply type this in the view:

**view**

```
echo $form->input('car_category_id', array('class' => 'short'));
```

Again, not to be pedantic, but the label should be *Car Category* instead of *Car Categories* as you have it now, since a Car can belong to only one category according to your data model.

If you want the ":" separator for all your labels, you can use CSS to add them. Check [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html) to find out how. You can also specify the `between` option for the form input.

**Tables**

Rename the table `carcategories` to `car_categories`
Rename the column `carcategory_id` in the cars table to `car_category_id`

Coming back to your actual problem:

```
Undefined property: CarsController::$CarCategory
```

This means that you cannot access `CarCategory` model from the `CarsController`. By default, the `CarsController` would manage the `Car` model. In order to manage the CarCategory model, you can do it in one of many ways:

- Using associations: `$this->Car->CarCategory->find( ... )`
- In your controller, set the $uses variable as follows: `var $uses = array('Car', 'Carcategory');`

You can load models on-the-fly as well (using `loadModel` or `ClassRegistry::init` if you're interested), but since you're fetching the list of Car Categories in the beforeFilter, you should stick to one of the above methods (preferably the associations).

Hope that helps. Remember to look *carefully* at the names of all your models, controllers, files and tables.

Comment: Thank you RabidFire, your answer was clear and so supportive. I will just only add that the table carcategories should renamed to car_categories, and not car_category as you've mentioned. However, it works fine with me. Now I want to return the category name and not the category   id as it does now. Can you help me please?    
Again thank you

Comment: Sorry about that, was a typo. Using `find('list')` will return (id, name) pairs by default. So, you should be seeing the names in the combo box, and the associated ids will be sent to the server when the form data is POSTed. If you want to return (name, name) pairs for some reason, you could use `find('list', array('fields' => ('name', 'name'))`

Comment: Thank you RabidFire for your helpful tips. It works for me now as it should be. I Just want to add something, that find->('list') is showing the id in my combo box, and to make it assign the id as a value and display the name I had to do  the follwoing :    
     $this->set('carCategories', $this->Car->CarCategory->find('list', array('fields'=>array('CarCategory.id', 'CarCategory.car_category_name'))));  
Again thank you

Comment: @Hassan - Rename `car_category_name` to `name` (however, it's already this way in the sample code you've provided) in your `car_categories` table. Then Cake will automagically do this for you (you don't have to specify the `fields` key). You could also enter the line `var $displayField = 'car_category_name'` in the `CarCategory` model.

Answer (score 0):

In your car controller the find should be

```
$this->set('car_categories',$this->Car->Carcategory->find('list', array('order' => 'name')));
```

Comment: Still not working and returns this error
Undefined property: AppModel::$Carcategory [APP\controllers\cars_controller.php, line 15]
 Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\flsooq\cake\app\controllers\cars_controller.php on line 15

Comment: check this u may get some idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234705/why-am-i-getting-an-undefined-property-error-when-my-relationships-seem-correct